# Using fixed-width fonts with Growl

Tags: macos, growl

I'd like to write a wrapper for `growlnotify` that growls output from [cowsay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cowsay).

```
$ cowsay 'this is cowsay'
 ________________ 
< this is cowsay >
 ---------------- 
        \   ^__^
         \  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||
```

I've hunted through all the available Growl themes & appearance options but can't work out how to change the font to fixed-width, so the ASCII-art output from cowsay isn't munged.

Could someone please tell me how to switch the font used by Growl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Growl styles are essentially just CSS and HTML.

1. First find your styles in `~/Library/Application
   Support/Growl/Plugins`.
2. Choose the theme you want to make monospaced. Make a backup copy of it.
3. Context-click on it and select "Show Package Contents"
4. Navigate into `Contents -> Resources`
5. Open the `default.css` file in your editor of choice.
6. Update the `font-family` declaration in `html, body` rule set to
   begin with the name of your preferred monospaced font, e.g. [`Ubuntu Mono`](http://font.ubuntu.com/).
7. Save.
8. Mooooooo!